# CPU idle when parallelising using Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork, deadlock

I've used Python's `multiprocessing` to parallelise a function on a list of various arguments, and each process would freeze halfway through. When this happens, I check `top` followed by `1` on the Ubuntu machine and see that the cores are all now mostly idle (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

This is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue


class Parallelisable:
    # Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992810/python-multiprocessing-across-different-files
    def _apply_function(self, function, args_queue):
        while not args_queue.empty():
            args = args_queue.get()
            # Apply function to arguments
            function(*args)

    def parallelise(self, function, args_list):
        queue = Queue()
        for args in args_list:
            queue.put(args)
        pool = Pool(None, self._apply_function, (function, queue,))
        pool.close()  # signal that we won't submit any more tasks to pool
        pool.join()  # wait until all processes are done



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define data_dir, output_dir, filenames and some_frozenset here
    # data_dir and output_dir are strings
    # filenames is a list of strings
    # some_frozenset is a frozenset of strings

    Parallelisable().parallelise(some_function, [(filename, data_dir, output_dir, some_frozenset) for filename in filenames])
```

I suspect that it is due to a deadlock.

I have come up with these possible explanations but they don't make much sense to me:

1. The `Parallelisable` object is a shared resource, with the lock acquired by one of the child processes at any one point in time and prevents a `self._apply_function()` call in multiple child processes. I don't think this is the case as I've had 2 child processes running at the same time. I'm guessing this can be solved by forcing child processes to [call `execve` using the `multiprocessing` `spawn` method](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/)
2. `function` in `parallelise()` and `_apply_function()` is a shared resource, similar to point 1 above
3. Some of my code wasn't in `__main__` but I don't see that as a problem since I'm running on Ubuntu not Windows
4. One of the arguments `(filename, data_dir, output_dir, some_frozenset)` isn't threadsafe, which shouldn't be the case since the first 3 are immutable strings, and the last is an immutable set of immutable strings

Is there anything I'm missing?

By the way, I think that I can rewrite the code above like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def parallelise_v2(function, args_list):
    with Pool(None) as pool:  # Use the "spawn" method if I want to call execve
        pool.starmap_async(function, args_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define data_dir, output_dir, filenames and some_frozenset here

    parallelise_v2(some_function, [(filename, data_dir, output_dir, some_frozenset) for filename in filenames])
```

Comment: One trick to get more answers to your coding question in stackoverflow would be making a minimum program than can **run**. Then, instead of looking at source code and trying to figure out what happened, people can run your code. It would be a very interesting case to use viztracer to check what's going on here, but not without some executable code.

Comment: is it possible your tasks are unequal in "size" so you've only got one process doing work once the rest are done? Or are your tasks io bound on disk or waiting on network resources or something? All your process could be working without using all your CPU. Echoing the above comment, if you provided a runnable example that repro'd the problem I'd look further into it.

Comment: Thanks @minker, that seems really useful, I'll look into it. Will `viztracer` also output the json/html file if the script is stuck halfway? I didn't give the actual code as it does certain things to files that are quite task-specific, I'll try to get some minimal code that replicates the situation.

Comment: @Macattack The tasks are not IO bound as it would otherwise show up with high "wa, IO-wait" values from the `top` command. Instead the CPU cores are all close to 100% "id, idle". I'm working on a server and as far as I know the code/CPU/files should be on the same machine, so it shouldn't be a network issue.

Comment: `viztracer` will output the file if the script is stuck. Just Ctrl-C out of it. Just remember you need `--log_multiprocess` for multiprocessing library when you use viztracer.

Comment: It seemed to be because the child processes were memory-intensive and Python silently killed them. The parent process simply waited for the child processes to return. I checked the reason for killed processes using `dmesg -T| grep -E -i -m10 -B20 'killed process'`, where `-m` specifies max number of matches to return and `-B` specifies number of lines before the match "killed process".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be because the child processes were memory-intensive and Python silently killed them. The parent process simply waited for the child processes to return. I checked the reason for killed processes using `dmesg -T| grep -E -i -m10 -B20 'killed process'`, where `-m` specifies max number of matches to return and `-B` specifies number of lines before the match "killed process".

For more possible reasons and troubleshooting tips, look at the question description and the comments in the question. They include a few things to look out for and the suggestion of `viztracer` to trace what happened. Quoting from @minker:

> `viztracer` will output the file if the script is stuck. Just Ctrl-C out of it. Just remember you need `--log_multiprocess` for `multiprocessing` library when you use `viztracer`.